# ¿Por qué no me muestra los valores capturados?

Tags: javascript, html, undefined

Saludos le escribo por aca, tengo un problema cuando capturo unos datos por una página `html` los datos los ingreso por unos `INPUT` y un `BUTTON` y cundo los quiero ver por `console.log` me los muestra `UNDEFINED`?

```
function recogerDatos(){
    var nombreUsuario = document.getElementById("name").Value;
    let telefonoUsuario = document.getElementById("phone").Value;
    let emailUsuario = document.getElementById("correo").Value;
    let passUsuario = document.getElementById("contrasena").Value;
    
    console.log(nombreUsuario);
    console.log(telefonoUsuario);
    console.log(emailUsuario);
    console.log(passUsuario );
}
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, por favor oprime [edit] y agrega también el `html` que has utilizado hasta ahora. Sería mejor que lo agregaras en conjunto en un fragmento de código `html/css/javascript` para que podamos ejecutarlo y ver el comportamiento actual.

Comment: Dos cosas: no recuerdo que javascript ignore mayúsculas. Por lo tanto debería ser `value` en minúsculas. Y en qué parte del HTML está el código?

Comment: hola Mateo si tenias razon la palabra "value" estaba mal escrita gracias soy nuevo en este mundo

Answer (score 0):

deberías intentar recuperar los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
var nombreUsuario = document.getElementById("name").value;
let telefonoUsuario = document.getElementById("phone").value;
let emailUsuario = document.getElementById("correo").value;
let passUsuario = document.getElementById("contrasena").value;
```

Javascript es case sensitive, y al intentar recuperar el dato con .Value, el dato solamente retornara *undefined*.

Espero que haya te servido.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias si tenía mal escrita la palabra value soy nuevo en este mundo